# When using the extract function on a file that has been uploaded to the database, var dumping it returns type of int

Tags: php, file

Using a html form the user uploads a file which is then submitted and sent as $_POST to php file. When using require($target_file) then extracting the $_POST of the file when var dumping it, it returns a integer of value 1 hwoever when it prints the contents of the file but its of type integer not string. Can someone explain why this happens and how I could go about fixing it. As I need to use the to generate some keywords for the file for a database system.

```
$target_file = $targetDir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

require($target_file);
$thefile = extract($_POST);
var_dump($thefile);
//Returns the contents of file and type Int(1)
$actfile = strval($thefile);
var_dump($actfile);
//Returns string(1)
```

How can I proceed with this as I need to use the string of the contents for further on in my code.

Comment: The [`extract` function](https://www.php.net/extract) takes each entry from an array and turns it into a variable in the current scope; I'm not sure what you expected it to return. Frankly, this feels like a *very* odd piece of code. The user uploads a file; you then *execute that file as PHP code* (I hope you *really* trust that user!); then you expect the file to overwrite the values in $_POST, which you would normally only read from; then you want to get *something* from that $_POST array? I suggest you take a *big* step back and figure out what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I am building a chatbot for a project for CS and this is for one of the segements of my project, all of this is being locally hosted. And the purpose of that code is just so that I can read the contents of the file which the user has uploaded. All I need is for the file to be read and it returns a string then I can just slot it into another piece of code that I have.

Comment: If you just want the contents of a file, you don't need *any* of this code. You need [file_get_contents](https://php.net/file_get_contents). Executing code from an uploaded file (which is what `require` does) would be very unusual, and I'm not sure how you got the impression that `$_POST` and `extract` were relevant at all. If for some reason the user really is uploading a file containing PHP code, please [edit] the question to show a sample upload file, and what you're trying to get from it; there's almost certainly still a better way than executing it.

Comment: @IMSoP your comment above was really helpful, from your explaination I understood that I didnt properly understant what $_POst and extract did. And also I didn't properly explain my question. I did not know that the file_get_contents existed even though I;ve gone through the php documentation someman times for functions I did not know that existed that was why I was using the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST variables are something, FILES variables are something else.
If you need file name, size, contents always use FILES.
The POST is used for other variables.
Try first to vardump FILES. Then access his variables. POST variables are the other variables sent by the form like input text, textarea and so on.

> $thefile = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmpname");